# Create custom convolution layer and compare two keras layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, compare

I am currently creating a network in keras to perform harmonic/percussive source separation on an audio spectrogram using a median filtering technique (http://dafx10.iem.at/papers/DerryFitzGerald_DAFx10_P15.pdf).

Given an input magnitude spectrogram **S**, and denoting the *i*th time frame as **S**<sub>i</sub>, and the *h*th frequency slice as **S**<sub>h</sub>, a percussion-enhanced spectrogram frame **P**<sub>i</sub> can be generated by performing median filtering on **S**<sub>i</sub> : **P**<sub>i</sub> = M{**S**<sub>i</sub>, **l**<sub>perc</sub>} where **M** denotes the median filtering and **l**<sub>perc</sub> is the filter length.  The individual percussion-enhanced frames **P**<sub>i</sub> are then combined to yield a percussion-enhanced spectrogram **P**.  Similarly, a harmonic-enhanced spectrogram frequency  slice **H**<sub>h</sub> can  be  obtained  by  median  filtering  frequency slice **S**<sub>h</sub> : **H**<sub>i</sub> = M{**S**<sub>h</sub>, **l**<sub>harm</sub>}.

Once you have **P** and **H**, you can see whether each frequency bin **S**<sub>h,i</sub> belongs either to the harmonic or the percussive source : if **H**<sub>h,i</sub> > **P**<sub>h,i</sub>, **S**<sub>h,i</sub> goes to the harmonic spectrogram and takes the value 0 in the percussive spectrogram, and vice versa.

In my network, given the input spectrogram and for a specific time frame **S**<sub>i</sub>, I need to compute the medians horizontally for each frequency h. This can be easily done with a lambda layer and tensorflow :

```
layer_H = Lambda(lambda x:tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(x[0], 50, axis=0))(layer)
```

Here, the length of the harmonic median filter **l**<sub>harm</sub> is the horizontal length of the input spectrogram. The output is a vector whose size is equal to the number of frequencies (in my case, 88).

The next step is where I am stuck right now : I need to compute the medians vertically for the current time frame **S**<sub>i</sub>, given the length of the percussive median filter **l**<sub>perc</sub>, and knowing that I want the resulting vector to be the same size as the input, so I have to be careful on each end of the the input (the size of the filter will be between **l**<sub>harm</sub> and **l**<sub>harm</sub>/2 depending on where we're at). This looks like some sort of convolution, for lack of a better word.

Once I have the two resulting vectors **H**<sub>i</sub> and **P**<sub>i</sub>, I want to compare them and assign each value of the original frame **S**<sub>i</sub> to either a percussive layer (**L**<sub>p</sub>) or a harmonic layer (**L**<sub>h</sub>). So, I have three different inputs, **H**<sub>i</sub>, **P**<sub>i</sub> and **S**<sub>i</sub>, and I want to end up with **L**<sub>p</sub> and **L**<sub>h</sub> by comparing **H**<sub>i</sub> and **P**<sub>i</sub>, and continue building my network from there. If **H**<sub>i,j</sub> > **P**<sub>i,j</sub>, then **L**p<sub>i,j</sub> = 0 and **L**h<sub>i,j</sub> = **S**<sub>i,j</sub>.

To sum up, I am stuck on two different problems :

1. How to compute the horizontal medians ?
2. How to implement in the network the operations that will allow me to go from **H**<sub>i</sub>, **P**<sub>i</sub> and **S**<sub>i</sub> to **L**<sub>p</sub> and **L**<sub>h</sub> ?

Thank you very much in advance !